What is the mathematical support for the formula $f_n = n f_1$, used to calculate the frequency of a standing wave?
could someone explain to me the mathematical support for the formula  $f_n = n f_1$. This formula refers to the fact that the frequency of a standing wave is equal to the number of antinodes times the fundamental frequency. If someone could explain to me where it comes from mathematically, I would be very grateful.

Let's start with a quick answer: the boundary conditions fix the frequencies of the harmonics. It's worth emphasizing that boundary conditions come from physics, not mathematics. Below, I'll consider the case of a string with fixed endpoints. But from a purely mathematical point of view, there is nothing special about these boundary conditions; they are one of an infinite set of possible boundary conditions. They are interesting because physically we often do look at strings with the endpoints fixed. However, they are also not the only possible boundary conditions, and you might find it interesting to reanalyze this problem when, say, one end of the string is fixed and the other end of the string is free (meaning the spatial derivative of the string at the boundary should vanish, instead of its displacement from equilibrium).
We can see where your formula comes from fairly directly using an argument with only algebra and trigonometry. Let's focus on waves on a string with fixed endpoints. If you accept that the frequency of the $n$-th harmonic $f_n$ is related to the wavelength $\lambda_n$ via $f_n \lambda_n = c_s$, where $c_s$ is the wave speed on the string, then $\lambda_n$ is fixed by the requirement that the endpoints are fixed. If the left endpoint is at $x=0$, then taking the spatial variation of the wave to be $\sin(2\pi x/\lambda_n)$ will guarantee that the wave takes the value zero at $x=0$ for all times. Then, if the right endpoint is at $x=L$, the condition $\sin(2\pi L/\lambda_n) = 0$ fixes $\lambda_n = L/n$, so that the height of the wave at the right endpoints is $\sin(2\pi n)$, which is zero. The requirement that $\lambda_n=L/n$, plus the relationship $\lambda_n f_n = c_s$, tells you that $f_n = n c_s / L$, which we can also write as $f_n = n f_1$, where $f_1 = c_s/L$ is the frequency of the first harmonic.
If the above doesn't satisfy you, here's a derivation with some more details, although giving the same argument.
Let $y(x,t)$ be the height of the string as a function of position and time. The governing equation is the wave equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} - c_s^2 \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$
where $c_s$ is a constant (the speed of sound). Solutions to this equation have the form
$$
y(x, t) = y_0 \cos(\omega t + \varphi) \sin(k x + \beta)
$$
where $\omega$ and $k$ obey the dispersion relation
$$
\omega = c_s k
$$
and $y_0, \varphi, \beta$ are constants.
You can verify $y(x,t)$ is a solution of the wave equation by plugging it in and checking explicitly.
What fixes $k$ and $\beta$ are the boundary conditions. Suppose the string has length $L$, and we fix the endpoints of the string so that $y(0, t) = y(L, t) = 0$. Then
$$
\beta=0, k = \frac{2\pi n}{L}
$$
where $n$ is an integer ($n=0, 1, 2, \cdots$). Let's just double check that. Since $\beta=0$, we have that $\sin(kx)=0$ whenever $x=0$, which was the first boundary condition. And, since $k=2\pi n /L$, we have that $\sin(kL) = \sin(2\pi n)=0$, which was the second boundary condition. We say that the integer $n$ labels the harmonic of the string -- in other words, we can talk about the $n$-th harmonic of the string being the harmonic where the wavenumber takes the value $k_n=2\pi n /L$.
Given this information, we have that the angular frequency of the $n$-th harmonic is
$$
\omega_n = c_s k_n = \frac{2 \pi c_s n}{L} = n \omega_1
$$
where we defined $\omega_1 \equiv 2\pi c_s / L$, the angular frequency of the first harmonic, with $n=1$.
Since $\omega = 2\pi f$, we can also equivalently write this in terms of the frequency of the $n$-th harmonic
$$
f_n = n f_1
$$
where the frequency of the first harmonic $f_1= c_s / L$.
